# Spree getting model name constant from the table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to accomplish the following inside Spree migrations:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
    table.constantize.update_all(user_id: 1)
end
```

:user_id is present in all the tables present in the database.

I want to update the :user_id column in all the tables to 1.

```
"spree_products".constantize
```

isn't returning "Spree::Product"

I have used the following code successfully for updating the user_ids:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
    Spree.const_get(table.gsub("spree_", "").classify).update_all(user_id: 1)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gsub `_` with `/` and use [classify](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify)

```
> "spree_products".gsub('_', '/').classify
# => "Spree::Product"
```

Comment: Thank you @santosh, I was trying to recall this but couldn't. Thanks again.